# JSONModel not working with Swift arrays

Tags: json, swift, jsonmodel

I am having some trouble using JSONModel in Swift.

I am trying to create a ToDo list app that would persist a collection of items so that the ToDo items are preserved when the app is closed. This is the code I use:

```
class ToDoItem: JSONModel {
    var name: String = ""
    var isCompleted: Bool = false
    var createdOn: NSDate = NSDate()
}

class ToDoList: JSONModel {
    var items: [ToDoItem] = []
}
```

I can convert a `ToDoItem` to JSON by calling `toJSONString()` but the same method doesn't work with `ToDoList`, it returns nil. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: unrelated to your question but I think you need to set `createdOn` in your init. What you currently have will use the same value for every ToDoItem (…at least I'm pretty sure - haven't run this code)

Comment: Those are just placeholder values. I use the init of the superclass and than manually fill the values in. I am new to the iOS ecosystem but this is how you usually handle things when doing persistence in Java.

Comment: I still didn't test JSONModel with Swift. Provided that things are rather unstable in Swift I guess I will wait a bit before implementing Swift compatibility

Comment: Luka, did you manage to solve this issue somehow?

Comment: Yes, by writing my own serialization routines... Last time I checked a few weeks ago there was still no way of getting this thing to work properly.

Comment: Hey Luka, did you get any solution, am facing same problem? Can you post some code?

Comment: Hey, the last time I check there was still no workaround. I haven't coded much in Swift in the last few months so a solution I'm not aware of may have been found. If you need a library for handling JSON objects try using SwiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONModel does not support Swift due to incompatibilities with the reflection supported by the Obj-C runtime. This reflection ability is currently required by JSONModel in order to resolve types correctly. [We are looking into alternative methods of defining the type mappings though.](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/issues/398)

Specifically, JSONModel relies on the use of protocols to determine the type of items in collection types, such as dictionaries, arrays, etc. Protocols defined in Swift are not visible at runtime - preventing JSONModel from deserializing collection types correctly.

For the time being, you have two options:

1. switch from JSONModel to another JSON (de)serialization library with support for Swift
2. define your models in Objective-C

I know this isn't ideal, but I'm afraid a workaround is not possible with the current JSONModel behavior.

Answer (score -1):

If your array is a member of some other class you can use a helper method.

Data class

```
@protocol Transaction
@end

@interface Transaction : JSONModel
  ...
@end
```

A "wrapper" class

```
@interface TransactionPage : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* pageNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* pageSize;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* totalRecords;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* totalPages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Transaction>* records;

- (NSArray<TphTransactionSummary*>*) recordsForSwift;  // <<< Helper method

@end
```

Implementation on the helper method

```
- (NSArray<TphTransactionSummary*>*) recordsForSwift {
    return self.records;
}
```