# JSONModel and Swift Array

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, jsonmodel

Is it possible to use an array in a subclass of JSONModel in Swift? Or is it a limitation as it is not updated yet?

If I do this in Objective-C, in the .h file:

```
@interface RecommendationModel : JSONModel
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<VenueModel>* recommendations;
@end
```

It works fine.

But, if I do this in Swift:

```
class RecommendationModel: JSONModel {

    var recommendations : [VenueModel] = []

}
```

It didn't work. The app runs, but when trying to read JSON, it breaks with the message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JSONModelProperty type not allowed', reason: 'Property type of App_iOS.RecommendationModel.recommendations is not supported by JSONModel.'

The JSON, and the `VenueModel` class are identical for Objective-C and Swift.

Any way to make it work in Swift?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742628/jsonmodel-not-working-with-swift-arrays

Comment: jsonmodel uses the objc runtime, it is not tested with swift

Comment: This is a duplicate. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742709/743957

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Because JSONModel doesn't understand the swift so you have to give objetive-c. Try this:

`var recommendations: NSArray = [VenueModel()]`

@marintodorov, can you verify?

Comment: the above method used but its not working? any other ways from JsonModel?