# Using JSONModel to parse array of custom models in Swift

Tags: swift, jsonmodel

I am using JSONModel for creation of complex data models. I have recently migrated to swift and face difficulties during parsing an array of custom data models.

class ABCDomain: JSONModel
{
    var sampleBool : Bool!
    var sampleArray : Array <XYZDomain>!
}

After parsing, when i access the sampleArray i get the message as "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type".

In Objective C,  we would be creating a protocol as well for the XYZDomain, while in Swift a compiler error stating redeclaration is thrown. 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* sampleArray;

Primitive data type like Bool as well always appears as nil in the datamodel
Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: JSONModel is not fully appropriate to Swift. You should consider it using in Objective C or find another library.

Comment: This is a duplicate. For an answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742709/743957

Answer (score 0):

I have found this as a good alternative.
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

I have been using this for a while and don't have a problem with it.